# Assign existing Gitlab runner to new project

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

So, I have owner privileges on some group in Gitlab (not privately hosted instance), and there is a registered runner that I want to assign to a new project in order to use it for CD (It is in use on other projects I am an owner at). However, I don't see it in CI/CD runners settings even though it is not locked for one project. I was also trying this https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/runners.html#enable-a-runner-in-project solution (API call) Gitlab provides but it seems like the runner does not exist (generic error, it says the page does not exist or I have no permission).
I thought it might be a permissions problem but it doesn't make sense (or does it?) because I have owner privileges. In docs they say: 
"If you are Master on a project where a specific Runner is assigned to, and the Runner is not locked only to that project, you can enable the Runner also on any other project where you have Master permissions.

To enable/disable a Runner in your project:

Visit your project's Settings > CI/CD
Find the Runner you wish to enable/disable
Click Enable for this project or Disable for this project"

and well, I can't find it. Does it sound like a bug/mistake on docs or my lack of knowledge? And if it is my lack of knowledge, do you have any ideas for possible solutions?

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR:
It seems like some kind of group permissions bug.
A possible workaround is to create another user and invite him to a project that uses that specific runner, as master (not owner), and then invite him to the project you want to assign that specific runner to. then, you will have that runner available under specific runners.

Ok, it seems to be a problem with gitlab/gitlab-runner permissions, or just a rather strange behavior. This is what someone wrote in the issues section of the project ( https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1322 ):

"Consider the following setup:

user_A is owner of project_1, runner_R is registered with project_1's token
user_A is owner of project_2

--> runner_R is NOT visible to user_A from project_2

user_A is promoted master of project_1

--> runner_R is now visible to user_A from project_2

hence my conclusions:

i don't need to be master of a project to select a runner from a project i own, being an owner works too
being a project owner is not sufficient for a project's runner to be visible to me from another project, i need to be master of the project where the runner was registered"

I hope it might be helpful to someone facing the same problem as me.